# Editing OFT with VBA code

Tags: vba, outlook, oft

I'm trying to edit an OFT with vba code

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

template = "T:\Coordination des interventions\Coordination des changements\Communications\Interruption de service planifiée - Environnements applicatifs Oracle - Copie.oft"

strNew = InputBox("Jour de la semaine")

strFind = "%>JourSemaine<%"


Dim oApp As Object, oMail As Object

Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set oMail = oApp.CreateItemFromTemplate(template)

With oMail
    'strFind = "Code:"
    'strNew = "Code:" & Cells(4, 3) ' for example
    .HTMLBody = Replace(oMail.HTMLBody, strFind, strNew)

    .Display

End With

End Sub
```

This is where I got an error 287 (my systeme is in french)

```
    .HTMLBody = Replace(oMail.HTMLBody, strFind, strNew)
```

Anybody have clue?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you set up a well-formed HTML markup. For example:

```
With oMail 
  'Set body format to HTML 
  .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML 
  .HTMLBody = "<HTML><BODY>Enter the message text here. </BODY></HTML>" 
  .Display 
End With
```

Calling the Replace method you may replace some HTML tags as well.

Answer (score 1):

Obvious thing to me, not that I am outlook vba expert, but if is purely a html issue as the person above me has said but failed to spell out - your *strFind* includes the html tags '>' and '<' so why haven't you added them in your *strNew*. If I am to assume rather that was just typo on your behalf and your actual code is replace `"Code:"` with `"Code: " + Cells(4, 3)` then I would be asking myself what is in Cells(4, 3) is it html encoded i.e. the common mistakes people make are does the text contain tags (e.g. '>' or '<') or ampersand ('&') then you need to change it with a replace function e.g. `Replace(Cells(4, 3), "&", "&amp;")` or find a predefined function that encodes it for you. In your case I am guessing being French perhaps you text contains uni-code characters like letters with accents and graves etc. that will also need to be encoded.